# Disable manual scroll in CSS

Tags: html, css, user-interface, scroll, css-transitions

I'm using CSS smooth scroll -  which is triggered by clicking a div.

Now I want to disable manual scrolling, so you can only scroll by clicking that div and not by actually scrolling.

Is it possible? Thx.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+dsiable+scroll+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

CSS overflow property can help the situation.
Give,

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

This will resist the scroll event over the section you are providing overflow hidden.

Please provide the overflow:hidden to the required section alone, so that it will not affect the other part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Using this little snippet below, you won't be able to scroll and the scroll bar wont be visible.

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

using `::-webkit-scrollbar` isn't a possibility because you will still be able to scroll.